# How to relate detected keypoints after auto-focus

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation, stereo-3d

I'm working with an stereo camera setup that has auto-focus (which I cannot turn off) and a really low baseline of less than 1cm.

**Auto-focus process can actually change any intrinsic parameter** **of both cameras** (as focal length and principal point, for example) and **without a fix relation** (left camera may add focus while right one decrease it). Luckily cameras always report the current state of intrinsics with great precision.

On every frame an object of interest is being detected and disparities between camera images are calculated. As baseline is quite low and resolution is not the greatest, performing stereo triangulation leads to quite poor results and for this matter several succeeding computer vision algorithms relay only on image keypoints and disparities.

Now, disparities being calculated between stereo frames cannot be directly related. If principal point changes disparities will be in very different magnitudes after the auto-focus process.

Is there any way to relate keypoint corners and/or disparities between frames after auto-focus process? For example, calculate where would the object lie in the image with the previous intrinsics?

Maybe using a bearing vector towards object and then seek for intersection with image plane defined by previous intrinsics?

Answer (score 0):

Quite challenging your project, perhaps these patents could help you in some way:

[Stereo yaw correction using autofocus feedback](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150049172A1/en)

[Autofocus for stereo images](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9485495B2/en)

[Depth information for auto focus using two pictures and two-dimensional Gaussian scale space theory](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7929801B2/en)